# PHP Work out colour saturation

Tags: php, colors, gd, rgb, hsv

lets say i have the following RGB values:

R:129
G:98
B:87

Photoshop says the saturation of that colour is 33%

How would i work out that percentage using PHP and the RGB values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773698/rgb-to-hsv-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [RGB to HSV in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773698/rgb-to-hsv-in-php)

Taking only the saturation bits from that code, and converting into a percentage:

```
function saturation($R, $G, $B) {  // 0-255
     $Min = min($R, $G, $B);
     $Max = max($R, $G, $B);
     return $Max == 0 ? 0 : (($Max - $Min) / $Max) * 100;
}
```

Alternately you could use the original code in the link above - the HSV values it returns are between 0.0 and 1.0, so you just need to multiply the saturation value by 100 to get your percentage.

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks for rewriting it to be much smaller, running this in every iteration of a 600 * 600 loop :P

Comment: This produces inaccurate results if `255` is not one of the passed values, and errors out if black (`0,0,0`) is passed.  Works great if you change the return statement to: `return $Max ? (($Max - $Min) / 255) : 0;`

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the division by zero. However, I am not sure why the second `$Max` should be replaced with 255, that's not in any other code I can see?

Answer (score 0):

[PEAR (PHP Extensions And Application Repository)](http://pear.php.net/) has a nice package called [Image_Color2](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_Color2) which allows you do to quick conversions between different color models:

```
include "Image/Color2.php";

$color = new Image_Color2(array(129,98,87));
$hsv = $color->convertTo('hsv');
$hsvArray = $hsv->getArray();

echo "Hue is " . $hsvArray[0] . "\n";
echo "Saturation is: " . $hsvArray[1] . "\n";
echo "Brightness is: " . $hsvArray[2];
```